# How to get the username in C/C++ in Linux?

Tags: c++, c, linux, posix

How can I get the actual "username" without using the environment (`getenv`, ...) in a program? Environment is C/C++ with Linux.

Comment: Which is a difference between c and c++ function? Do you mean class method??

Comment: I just have to don't use c function

Comment: All of POSIX API is defined as C functions, which can be called all the same in C++. I don't understand your restriction.

Comment: This restriction doesn't make any sense... if you need to interact with a POSIX operating system you *have* to get down to C (or to assembly). And how do you define a "C++ function"? The C++ standard library doesn't provide anything for that, and even if it did it would just be a wrapper for `getlogin_r`.

Comment: Restriction ? Professors ! :)

Comment: For me, a C++ function is a function who don't need a C include (cstdlib, cstdio, cstring, ...)

Comment: @Armed9Gagger: I'm quite sure that he didn't mean what you said, because it wouldn't make any sense... can you tell us the exact words he wrote in the assignment? Probably he just doesn't you to write a C-style function (with `char *` & co.), but a C++ wrapper (with `std::string`, ...) for `getlogin_r`.

Comment: @Armed9Gagger: technically `cstdlib` & co. are C++ includes (providing the legacy C library inside the `std` namespace). Still, POSIX headers aren't included in standard C, are operating system APIs intended to be used from several languages (mainly C and C++).

Comment: I cant use the C standard library ! It's a restriction of my professors.

Comment: @Armed9Gagger: `getlogin_r()` - and in general all the POSIX APIs - is not in the C standard library.

Comment: No other possibility to get the username ? In a file on the proc/ ? I search but not find ...

Comment: If you cannot use any C function, you cannot achieve your homework. There is no C++ only standard library for that. Unless you use a C++ library like Qt.

Comment: "C standard library" is different from "C functions". You need to use the operating system API (such as POSIX or WinAPI) which is provided as C functions and available in your compiler, it but doesn't belong to the standard library. You can use it and use this explanation for your professors.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

The function **`getlogin_r()`** defined in `unistd.h` returns the username. See `man getlogin_r` for more information.

Its signature is:

```
int getlogin_r(char *buf, size_t bufsize);
```

Needless to say, this function can just as easily be called in C or C++.

Comment: @Armed9Gagger, there is no API in the C++ library for these things which are defined in POSIX. C++ is *supposed* to use POSIX functions.

Comment: Note getlogin_r returns the name of the user logged into the controlling terminal of a process. This may be different than the user the job is running as. This function will also fail if you are not attached to a controlling terminal (e.g., when a process is daemonized).

Comment: getlogin() this is simpler

Comment: This requires TTY to be present - if you're dispatching your applications through some kind of scheduler this will probably fail.. see Nemanja Boric's answer for a more "robust" version

Answer (score 62):

From http://www.unix.com/programming/21041-getting-username-c-program-unix.html :

```
/* whoami.c */
#define _PROGRAM_NAME "whoami"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pwd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  register struct passwd *pw;
  register uid_t uid;
  int c;

  uid = geteuid ();
  pw = getpwuid (uid);
  if (pw)
    {
      puts (pw->pw_name);
      exit (EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }
  fprintf (stderr,"%s: cannot find username for UID %u\n",
       _PROGRAM_NAME, (unsigned) uid);
  exit (EXIT_FAILURE);

}
```

Just take main lines and encapsulate it in class:

```
class Env{
    public:
    static std::string getUserName()
    {
        uid_t uid = geteuid ();
        struct passwd *pw = getpwuid (uid);
        if (pw)
        {
            return std::string(pw->pw_name);
        }
        return {};
    }
};
```

For C only:

```
const char *getUserName()
{
  uid_t uid = geteuid();
  struct passwd *pw = getpwuid(uid);
  if (pw)
  {
    return pw->pw_name;
  }

  return "";
}
```

Comment: Chances are that you can't use C *standard libraries*, not *all C functions*. You are required to directly or indirectly use C functions to perform your task.

Comment: To be pedantic, isn't your program missing a endpwent() call?

Comment: @NemanjaBoric Can't you just use argv[0] to get the program name, even if it is changed after compilation?

Comment: @TheXGood Ah, you mean for `_PROGRAM_NAME`. Yeah, that would do, this is just the example from the link I've pasted.

Comment: @Dr.PersonPersonII "isn't your program missing a endpwent() call" - That's to be used after one or more calls to getpwent(), which the current and earlier versions of the reply didn't use AFAICT, so no.

Answer (score 4):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
int main()
{
    std::string Username = getlogin();
    std::cout << Username << std::endl;
    return 0 ;
}
```

Another way is this -

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
       cout << system("whoami");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `char *cuserid(char *s)` found in `stdio.h`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_USERID_LENGTH 32

int main()
{
  char username[MAX_USERID_LENGTH];
  cuserid(username);
  printf("%s\n", username);
  return 0;
}
```

See for more details:

1. https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/cuserid.html
2. https://serverfault.com/questions/294121/what-is-the-maximum-username-length-on-current-gnu-linux-systems

Comment: `cuserid()` [has been removed from the POSIX standard](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getlogin.html#tag_16_203_08): "The information provided by the cuserid() function, which was originally defined in the POSIX.1-1988 standard and subsequently removed, can be obtained by the following:

`getpwuid(geteuid())`"

Answer (score 1):

working a little bit through modern c++ specs

```
static auto whoAmI = [](){ struct passwd *tmp = getpwuid (geteuid ());
  return tmp ? tmp->pw_name : "onlyGodKnows"; 
}
```

Comment: any reason why this should be a lambda instead of a normal function/class?

Comment: In the context I was writing the code,  a local function was the proper hiden..
IMHO a by hand class if nothing else is required could be avoided through functions(as your suggests)/lambdas which (among other things) it's nothing else than a executable object already built by the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <pwd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

// Return username or nullptr if unknown.
const char* username() {
    const passwd* pw = getpwuid(geteuid());
    return pw == nullptr ? nullptr : pw->pw_name;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Today I had  to do the same thing, but didn't like to include any OS specific headers.  So here is what you can do in a cross-platform way without resorting to any Linux/Windows specific headers:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <memory>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <array>
#include <regex>

std::string execute_command(std::string cmd) 
{
    std::array<char, 128> buffer;
    std::string result;
    
    #if defined(_WIN32)
        #define POPEN _popen
        #define PCLOSE _pclose
    #elif defined(unix) || defined(__unix__) || defined(__unix)
        #define POPEN popen
        #define PCLOSE pclose
    #endif

    std::unique_ptr<FILE, decltype(&PCLOSE)> pipe(POPEN(cmd.c_str(), "r"), PCLOSE);
    if (!pipe) 
    {
        throw std::runtime_error("popen() failed!");
    }
    while (fgets(buffer.data(), buffer.size(), pipe.get()) != nullptr) 
    {
        result += buffer.data();
    }
    return result;
}
std::string get_current_username()
{
    #if defined(_WIN32)
        // whoami works on windows as well but it returns the name 
        // in the format of `computer_name\user_name` so instead
        // we use %USERNAME% which gives us the exact username.
        #define USERNAME_QUERY "echo %USERNAME%" 
    #elif defined(unix) || defined(__unix__) || defined(__unix)
        #define USERNAME_QUERY "whoami"
    #endif
    auto username = execute_command(USERNAME_QUERY);
    // this line removes the white spaces (such as newline, etc)
    // from the username.
    username = std::regex_replace(username, std::regex("\\s"), "");
    return username;
    
}
```

This works just fine on both Linux and Windows and is C++11 compatible!

Test it online: https://paiza.io/projects/e/xmBuf3rD7MhYca02v5V2dw?theme=twilight