# Get logged in user in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Desktop

Tags: c, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04

I'm working on a C application in which I need the name of the currently logged in user. I have tried using `getlogin()` and `getlogin_r()` with no success **(tested on multiple systems with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS)**. The application will run as root so I cannot use the environment variables.

Both `getlogin()` and `getlogin_r()` work just fine on other Ubuntu 17.04/17.10/18.04(beta) so I don't understand why it doesn't work in 16.04.

Here is a code snippet that I used to test:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <pwd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char user[512] = {0};
    int ret = getlogin_r(user, 512);
    if ( ret != 0){
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to get User name. Return: %d\n", ret);
    }
    else{
        fprintf(stdout, "Username: %s\n", user);
    }

    char *lgn;
    struct passwd *pw;
    if ((lgn = getlogin()) == NULL || (pw = getpwnam(lgn)) == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Get of user information failed.\n");
    }

    struct passwd *pwd = getpwuid(getuid());
    if (pwd){
       fprintf(stdout, "Success! Username: %s\n", pwd->pw_name);
    }else
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed");

    return 0;
}
```

This is the output generated when I execute the code as root:

```
Unable to get User name. Return : 2 
Get of user information failed.
Success! Username: root
```

`getpwuid` returns the details of the user running the process so it is not helpful.

I'm kind of stuck now and any help is highly appreciated.

Output using `strerror()`

```
getlogin_r() : No such process
getlogin() : No such file or directory
Success! Username: root
```

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8953424/how-to-get-the-username-in-c-c-in-linux)'s a solution that might work for you.

Comment: For more meaningful errors, try `perror()` and/or `strerror()`

Comment: @FelixPalmen I've added the output from using `strerror()`. But those don't make any sense to me. :/

Comment: @BálintBudavölgyi Neither of those answers work for me. I have already tried.

Comment: @Koderkid are you sure? "No such process" would be ESRCH, this isn't documented as a possible error code from `getlogin_r()` in the manpage. I **think** code 2 would be ENOENT, which in context of `getlogin_r()` means there wasn't a matching entry found in [utmp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utmp).

Comment: And, as `getuid()` returns 0, are you sure you're running this program from the terminal you're logged on as a normal user? otherwise, there's no way to know which user id you actually want, after all, you're on a multitasking/multiuser system.

Comment: @FelixPalmen The application needs to run as root. So I run it with sudo which is why `getuid()` returns 0. I need the name of the logged in user for logging purposes.

Comment: @Koderkid well, check your utmp :) And then, if it's an option to make your own program suid root instead of using sudo, this would simplify things, because the real uid will stay that of the calling process, so `getuid()` won't return 0 (but `geteuid()` will).

Comment: @FelixPalmen Ok. I think I might be able to come up with a way to get it from utmp. Thank you! :)