# Reference Linux username in string to open file

Tags: c++, file-io, iostream

I have a config file which contains the path to another file which needs to be opened. This file path references the Linux username:

```
/root/${USER}/workspace/myfile.txt
```

where $USER should be translated to the Linux username.

This doesn't work and because the string is stored in my config file, I cannot use `getenv()`.

Is there another way to achieve this?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/getenv

Comment: There are ways to [get an environment variable](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getenv.3.html), and from that construct the filename.

Comment: The problem is these strings are read from a config file

Comment: There are many ways to search for, extract and replace sub-strings in C++. Regular expressions comes to mind. Use in combination with `getenv`.

Comment: I have just updated the question to reflect I cannot really use getenv()

Comment: ok, look for variable interpolation in c/c++, e.g. http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/wordexp.3.html or https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/172644/c-environment-variable-expansion

Comment: Why can't you use `getenv()`?

Comment: 'I cannot use getenv' Why not, what is stopping you? Just because $USER is only a part of your string does not stop you using getenv.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the username in C/C++ in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8953424/how-to-get-the-username-in-c-c-in-linux)

Comment: @john Thank you for your valuable contribution. I will take it under advisement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [wordexp](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/wordexp.3.html) to translate "~" which is a `UNIX` path element meaning the HOME directory. Something like this:

```
#include <wordexp.h>

std::string homedir()
{
    std::string s;
    wordexp_t p;
    if(!wordexp("~", &p, 0))
    {
        if(p.we_wordc && p.we_wordv[0])
            s = p.we_wordv[0];
        wordfree(&p);
    }
    return s;
}
```

And then extract the username from the returned path.

But I normally use `std::getenv()` like this:

```
auto HOME = std::getenv("HOME"); // may return nullptr
auto USER = std::getenv("USER"); // may return nullptr
```

Answer (score 2):

Get the username with `getenv`, replace `$USER` in the path with it.

Very straightforward example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>

int main()
{
    std::string path = "/root/$USER/workspace/myfile.txt";
    const char* user = std::getenv("USER");
    int pos = path.find("$USER");
    if (user != nullptr && pos >= 0)
    {
        path.replace(pos, 5, user);
        std::cout << path << std::endl;
    }
}
```