# How to create a csv file in an other folder linux with C++

Tags: c++, linux, server, directory, path

I have the problem that I want to create an folder outside of the folder where my actual code is running.
My folder structure on the Linux server lokes like following:

neural-network/src

In the src folder my code is running. But I would like to have my csv output file in the "neural-network" folder.

My code looks like this:

std::ofstream myFile_testing_results;

myFile_testing_results.open("/home/x5228/neural-network/actualTestPredictions.csv");

This is working fine. My problem is that when some other user on the linux server uses this code its not working, because my username (x5228) is included in the path. Are there some suggestion how can I get rid of this problem ? the folder structure "neural-network/src" looks for every user the same but I could be that there are some other folders before depeding on the user.

I was already trying it in this way:

myFile_testing_results.open("/neural-network/actualTestPredictions.csv");

but it is not working out. And I would prefer a similar way, because I dont know the whole folder structure of other users

Comment: There are many ways to do it. You could e.g. fetch the username and build your predefined paths, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8953424/how-to-get-the-username-in-c-c-in-linux. Generally, my preferred way would be to pass root paths as arguments or via the preprocessor. Depends on the rest of your setup.

Comment: @Cedric is there also an other way then go over the user because maybe the user is having an other folder structure

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. If each user wants to place the files in a different place, then this should be an input argument of the program. How do you expect to hard code a path that may differ between users?

Comment: Use `myFile_testing_results.open("../actualTestPredictions.csv");`